# Get Post data after clicking submit data of webcontrol

Tags: c#, firebug, web-controls, postdata

I use webcontrol to view the website content form. After click submit button of the any form from any register site for example. How can I get the post data as the firebug does?

this the example post data I get by firebug

> sitetitle=[$PostTitle$]&notify=B&noprice=1&sitedescription=[$PostContent$]&sitecatid=11&subcatid=85&expire_days=29&cityid=1&subcity=Ba+%C4%90%C3%ACnh&submit_post=%C4%90%C4%83ng+tin&v=&siteid=&mode=&flag=&lptime=1345045566&quickpost=0

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
var data = context.Request["expire_days"]; 

//Theses lines permit your to return expire_day
```